# Custom scroll view - image outside the frame

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, scroll

I would like to make an infinite scrolling view for iPad. The scrolling works, only when I add pictures to my customized scrollview class, it appears out of the view's frame too (so I have  view, which has a UIScrollView on it. This scroll view is connected with my CustomScroll.h :UIScrollView and CustomScroll.m files). Why do the images appear outside the view's frame (the view's frame is set in nib file to 320x420)?

CustomScroll.h:UIScrollView

A part from CustomScroll.m file:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])){
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000, 416);
    [self setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

    for (int i=1; i<=4; i++){
        [self addImageAtPosition:i];
    }

    //todo: to replace with the method: addFirstElementToTheEnd
    UIImageView *image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"]];
    [image1 setFrame:CGRectMake(5*320, 0, 320, 416)];
    [self addSubview:image1];
    [image1 release];

    //todo: to replace with the method: addLastElementToTheBeginning
    UIImageView *image2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.jpg"]];
    [image2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0*320, 0, 320, 416)];
    [self addSubview:image2];
    [image2 release];

}

return self;
```

}

```
- (void)addImageAtPosition:(NSInteger)position{
    UIImageView *tempImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", position]]];
    [tempImage setFrame:CGRectMake((position * 320), 0, 320, 416)];
    [self addSubview:tempImage];
    [tempImage release];
}

- (void)recenterIfNecessary{
    CGFloat currentOffsetX = [self contentOffset].x;

    if (currentOffsetX > 1600.00){
        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(320, [self contentOffset].y );
    }
    if (currentOffsetX < 320.00){
        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(5*320, [self contentOffset].y);
    }
}

- (void) layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self recenterIfNecessary];

}
```

TY.